# Upload form doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm trying to upload images to folder and path in the MySQL. But when I try I get error.
Here is the form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="caption" /><br/><br />
     <input type="file" name="name" /><br />
     <input type="submit" id="upload" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is upload.php

```
<?php

define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 2000000);

$permitted = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$caption = $_POST['userfile']['caption'];
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

// make a new image name
$ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
// generate the random file name
$randName = md5(rand() * time());

// image name with extension
$myFile = $randName . '.' . $ext;
// save image path
$path = "upload/" . $myFile;

if (in_array($fileType, $permitted) && $fileSize > 0
    && $fileSize <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $path);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "Error uploading image file";
        exit;
    } else {
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "image");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s<br/>", mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO images (caption, name, size, type, file_path) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        $conn = $db->prepare($query);
        if ($conn == TRUE) {
            $conn->bind_param("siss",$caption, $myFile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path);
            if (!$conn->execute()) {
                echo 'error insert';
            } else {
               // echo "<img src=\"upload/'". $myFile .\"'/>";
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
        } else {
            die("Error preparing Statement");
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'error upload file';
}
} else {
echo 'error'; **<==== I get this error**
}
?>
```

The error I get is on the last Else/echo 'error'. I don't know what can be the problem.

EDIT://

Now successfully inserting images to DB but doesn't insert NAME and PATH?

Comment: You have 4 types but 5 values in here: `$conn->bind_param("siss",$caption, $myFile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path);`, after `header('Location:...` you should also put in `exit;` to stop the script.

Comment: I was writed `sissi` not `ssiss`. I don't understand what is the different of this. Now work fine. Write and save. Thank's

Comment: `si` means, the first param is a `[s]tring`, the second param is an `[i]nteger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code has

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {}
```

But in the form there is nothing called upload, so add the submit button as

```
<input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" value="submit" />
```

submit button needs a name which you are missing.

Also about the notice

YOu should have something like in the PHP file

```
    $caption = $_POST['caption'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
```

AND

```
<input type="file" name="name" /><br />
```

needs to be changed to

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" /><br />
```

Comment: Ok, now I get error on `userfile` on line 15,16,17,18,19 is Undefined index and the error is on  `echo 'error upload file';`

Comment: Yes, this is ok now. Changed to `['name']...` tnx

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the name attribute for your input submit,try providing name attribute

```
<input type="submit" id="upload" value="submit" name="upload"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_FILES['userfile']
```

but in your form:

```
<input type="file" name="name" /><br />
```

should be

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" /><br />
```

Learn to debug your code ;)